# Strange incompatibility between several packages (options)

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, babel, cleveref, front-matter

The compilation of the following MCE fails with the error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 29.
<inserted text> 
                \fi
```

Interestingly, as soon as:

- one of the packages (options), except `csquotes` which isn't actually involved, or text is removed, this error doesn't arise anymore,
- both the two packages in comments are loaded, this error doesn't arise anymore, but a new one appears:

  ```
   ! Use of \label@optarg doesn't match its definition.
   \@ifnextchar ... \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {
                                                     #2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f...
   l.10 \listoffigures
  ```

Do you see what's going on? (Sorry for the two questions (for the two errors) in the same post, but they are intermixed.)

```
\documentclass{book}
% \usepackage{tocbibind}
% \usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: The culprit seems to be `refsegment=chapter`: with it the `Incomplete \iffalse` eventually appears (maybe after the other error if `titlesec` and `tocbibind` are loaded.

Comment: \pagenumber{Roman} seems to be the problem. I bet greek redefines that.

Comment: @egreg `refsegment=chapter` is not the only one culprit: if it is there, but the `greek` option is removed, the `Incomplete \iffalse` error disappears as well.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But with `greek` and without `refsegment=chapter`, the `Incomplete \iffalse` error disappears.

Comment: sure can happen. I mean greek redefines \@Roman and this then can fail in various places, you only need some code which tries to write \thepage and doesn't expect an not expandable command there.

Comment: cleverref, babel and `\pagenumbering{Roman}blub \label{abc}` is already enough to get a break.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed :) I'll report to the maintainers of these two packages.

Comment: well the main culprit is cleverref, it does `\edef\@tempb{\thepage}` instead of `\protected@edef`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't like to get garbage like `\newlabel{x}{{}{{\fontencoding  {OT1}\selectfont  I}}}` in my `.aux` file anyway.

Comment: @egreg no, but I'm not sure how to solve this problem in a general way. I mean some scripts want to do special typesetting with thepage and this clashes with the needs of the label system (spanish has a similar problem).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay: reported only to the `cleverref`'s maintainer :)